# set order_with_respect_to as foreign key of foreign key in django orderable

Tags: python, django

My models:

```
Class A(Orderable, Slugged):
   a = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
   class Meta:
        ordering = ("_order",)

Class B(Orderable, Slugged):
   a = models.ForeignKey(A, null=True, blank=True)
   b = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
   class Meta:
        ordering = ("_order",)
        order_with_respect_to = "a"

Class C(Orderable, Slugged):
   b = models.ForeignKey(B, null=True, blank=True)
   c = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
   class Meta:
        ordering = ("_order",)
        order_with_respect_to = "b__a"
```

How can i achive this?
I want "C" class  order_with_respect_to "A" class.
Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You might try to inherit `C.Meta` from `A.Meta`:

```
class C(Orderable, Slugged):
    ...
    class Meta(A.Meta):
        pass # C.order_with_respect_to is equal to A.order_with_respect_to
```